Verbos denominais formados pelo prefixo a+
Alguém sabe qual é a regra da morfologia que explica como o prefixo prefixo a+ muda também a classe sintática da base?
Por exemplo, há muitos verbos com o prefixo a+ que são formados de bases nominais:

batata (nome feminino) -> abatatar (verbo)

calor (nome masculino) -> acalorar (verbo)


mas não existem estes verbos sem prefixo:

batata (nome feminino) -> batatar (verbo)

calor (nome masculino) -> calorar (verbo)


Como estes últimos casos não existem acho que não podemos explicar a mudança de base nominal para verbal por uma derivação regressiva. Mas segundo o que percebo em geral os prefixos, por si só, não são responsáveis por mudar a classe sintática da base... Não encontro uma referência que explique bem isto.

Duas fontes interessantes: https://openaccess.blucher.com.br/download-pdf/520/22839  e  https://apl.pt/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/2001-31.pdf

@stafusa obrigado pelas referências, vou lê-as e quando terminar escrevo uma auto-resposta! Normalmente pesquiso isto sozinho, mas desta vez uma indicação na direção certa deu-me moral :)

Vejamos, alguns verbos se prestem á essa operação, nem todos já se criaram.  Por exemplo: Origem etimológica:a- + besta + -alhar.
"abestalhar", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2024, https://dicionario.priberam.org/abestalhar. Ou seja, se usa o substantivo, se adiciona um prefixo: a, e alhar no final. Outro: Origem etimológica:a- + bruto + -alhar.
"abrutalhar", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2024, https://dicionario.priberam.org/abrutalhar. Em todo caso, se usa o substantivo. Eu não diria base nominal aqui.

Tambem existe: em + rar: poeira: empoeirar. A formação morfica se explica aqui: https://www.normaculta.com.br/estrutura-das-palavras-elementos-morficos/
